# Code doesn't work in template

Tags: python, django

My problem is basically the same code doesn't work in django template, but it works 'python'. Keys in results dict are strings and values are 'collections.Counter' type. I'm using Django 1.6.1.
Here's the code

```
for k,v in results.items():
    for a,b in v.items():
        print a,':',b
```

Template:

```
{% for k,v in results.items %}
    {% for a,b in v.items %}
        {{ a }}, {{ b }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Error I'm getting is:

```
 'int' object is not iterable
```

and pointing to second for loop line. How can I fix it?

Sample:

```
for k,v in results.items():
    print k,v
    for a,b in v.items():
        print a,':',b
OUTPUT:
question1 Counter({u'1': 3, u'': 1, u'2': 1})
1 : 3
 : 1
2 : 1
question2 Counter({u'q': 3, u'': 1, u'w': 1})
q : 3
 : 1
w : 1
question3 Counter({u'a': 2, u'': 2, u's': 1})
a : 2
 : 2
s : 1
```

Comment: can you show a sample input dictionary ? (example the out put of the first code snippet ?)

Comment: It should work : Try `{% for a,b in v.iteritems %}`

Comment: @karthikr still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduce it in a `./manage.py shell`:

```
from django.template import Context, Template
from collections import Counter

t = Template('{% for k,v in results.items %}{% for a,b in v.items %}[{{ a }}, {{ b }}]{% endfor %}{% endfor %}')
c = Context({"results": {"question1": Counter({'1': 3, '': 1, '2': 1})}})
t.render(c)
```

And of course I obtained the same error. This is because `items` inside the `for` keyword is not a simple call to `dict.items` and do not support `Counter`.

Try to convert your `Counter` in a `dict` when you create the `Context`:

```
from django.template import Context, Template
from collections import Counter

t = Template('{% for k,v in results.items %}{% for a,b in v.items %}[{{ a }}, {{ b }}]{% endfor %}{% endfor %}')
c = Context({"results": {"question1": dict(Counter({'1': 3, '': 1, '2': 1}))}})
t.render(c)
```

You will obtain:

```
u'[1, 3][, 1][2, 1]'
```